# How to store state on a node for a visitor pattern?

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I have an architecture that uses the visitor pattern to implement a number of passes over a tree (an AST as it happens). In one of the passes I need to associate some data with a node (`nodeX`) and then from some point below it get my data from a reference to the `nodeX`. I want to do this in a way that doesn't push the implementation of the visitor/pass into the tree nodes.

*Is there some neat way to make that work?*

Ideas:

- `void*` on each node (ugly, not type safe)
- `hash_map<Node,Data>` (not as clean as I'd like, and who owns it?)

Answer (score 1):

The hash_map sounds like the best way to me. The visitor would own it.